# ros2 launch: How to select parameters yaml file depending on parameter?

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use a parameter (ns) to select the yaml file to load for parameters.  I have a hard time finding how to do it...  Is there a better way to do it?

I want to do something like:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    ns_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument("ns", default_value=TextSubstitution(text="/dji0"))
    location_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument("location", default_value=TextSubstitution(text="granso"))

    location_config = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('lrs_wdb'),
        'config',
        f'location_{LaunchConfiguration('location')}.yaml'
    )
    
    return LaunchDescription([
        ns_arg,        
        Node(
            package='lrs_wdb',
            output='screen',
            emulate_tty=True,            
            namespace=LaunchConfiguration('ns'),
            executable='wdb',
            name='wdb',
            parameters=[location_config]
        )
    ])
```

But this is not working since "LaunchConfiguration('ns')" is an object. And googling it I did not find a strightforward way to get the value.  So any suggestions how to solve this? I could use an environment variable I suppose but I do not think that is a good solution since for example ns is specified with a parameter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395779/ros2-launch:-how-to-select-parameters-yaml-file-depending-on-parameter?/) by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2022-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With launch substitutions, you can build strings like this with tuples. Sure there's more elegant ways to create the tuple, but this works.

```
location_config = (get_package_share_directory('lrs_wdb'),
                   '/config/location_',
                   LaunchConfiguration('location'), '.yaml')

return LaunchDescription([
    Node(package='lrs_wdb',
         executable='wdb',
         parameters=[location_config]
    )
])
```

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2022-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on 2022-02-11**:
Thanks, it worked.  Is this documented somewhere that you can use a tuple? Or is it some Python standard?

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2022-02-11**:
If it is documented, I don't know where. I can say that this feature comes from the `launch.utilities.perform_substitutions_impl.py` file.